# How to create a data frame with dimension M x N in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to do it?

I'm stuck with this:

```
m <- 10 # nof row
n <- 5  # nof column

# We will fill each cell with '0'

all <-c()
for (i in 1:m) {
   row_i <- c(rep(0,n))
   all <- c(all,row_i)
}
```

Which only create 1 row as output.

Comment: @mdsumner: Oops sorry, I've corrected it.

Comment: The answers below are best, but your code would work if you use `rbind` not `c`, i.e.  `all <- rbind(all,row_i)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use a matrix? `data.frames` are for storing columns of varying types.

So,

```
m = 10
n = 5
mat = matrix(0, nrow = m, ncol = n)
```

If you really want a `data.frame`, coerce to one - the column names will simply be a default:

```
dat = as.data.frame(mat)
names(dat)
[1] "V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5"
```

The problem with your approach is that you simply append the values one after the other, ignoring the dimensions you want. You can do it like this, but it's not a good idea to grow data, better to allocate it all upfront as above. Also, this results in a matrix anyway, which I think is what you should use.

WARNING: bad code ahead!

```
m <- 10 # nof row
n <- 5  # nof column

all <- NULL
for (i in 1:m) {
  row_i <- c(rep(0,n))
  all <- rbind(all,row_i)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This produces data.frame filled with zeros.

```
as.data.frame(lapply(structure(.Data=1:N,.Names=1:N),function(x) numeric(M)))
```

Comment: mdsummer solution is more elegant but my solution can be extended to generate different classes for columns.